# How to keep an SSH tunnel open in Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, connection, putty, ssh-tunnel

I use SSH tunneling to connect  to a server (Basically IPython notebook instance) to do some computation work. My computations are intense and take need a lot of time to finish. Due to this, most of the time PuTTY (or server) aborts the SSH connection as it thinks there are no packets moving to and from.

What is the simplest way to keep the SSH open for a long time? I am running Windows and I can not install Cygwin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PuTTY Configuration window, go to the *Connection* page and set the *Sending of null packets to keep session alive*.

See [Using keepalives to prevent disconnection](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-keepalive).

[image]